# Legend placement with xtline x y, legend(position(6))

Tags: stata

I am trying to place my legend at the bottom of my graph when I am plotting two variables in my xtset data. Using `help legend`, I have read on the `position(clockposstyle)`, but I can not get the legend to show up at `position(6)`. Instead it always stays at `position(3)`.

MRE:

```
* Clearing existing data and setting up
clear
set obs 64

* Creating the panel identifiers
gen country_id = ceil(_n/4)
gen year = 2001 + mod(_n-1, 4) + 1

* Labelling countries for readability
label define country_label 1 "Country01" 2 "Country02" 3 "Country03" 4 "Country04" ///
    5 "Country05" 6 "Country06" 7 "Country07" 8 "Country08" 9 "Country09" 10 "Country10" ///
    11 "Country11" 12 "Country12" 13 "Country13" 14 "Country14" 15 "Country15" 16 "Country16"
label values country_id country_label

* Setting up the panel data structure
xtset country_id year

* Generating random variables x and y
set seed 0
gen x = rnormal()
gen y = rnormal()

* Display the first 20 observations
list country_id year x y in 1/20, sepby(country_id)

xtline x y, legend(position(6))
```

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1737384-legend-placement-for-xtline-var1-var2-legend-position-6-does-not-work